# Norm of a vector is determined by evaluation of linear functionals on it: can this be proved without the Hahn-Banach theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed vector space over the field of real numbers, $\mathbb R$, and let $x_0 \in V$ be fixed. I know how to prove
$$\|x_0\| = \sup_{f \in V^*, \|f\| = 1} |f(x_0)|$$
using the Hahn-Banach theorem. But I am really curious to know if anyone can see a simple way to show this *without* using the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: You need some form of Hahn-Banach to have enough functionals  to get the equality.

Comment: Could you give this a title that describes the  question, instead of just its hypotheses?

Answer (score 2):

There is a model of ZF axiomatic for which $(\ell_\infty/c_0)^*=\{0\}$. Of course in this case you can't prove the desired identity becasue there is no non-trivial functionals at hand. Note that in this model Hahn-Banach theorem does not hold, therefore you **must** use Hahn-Banach theorem in ZFC to prove that identity.

See [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5351/whats-an-example-of-a-space-that-needs-the-hahn-banach-theorem?rq=1) for more details